# Why won't this simple linear regression with gradient descend works?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm new in machine learning and I'm trying to do a linear regression for f(x)=kx by **gradient descend.**
And

```
d(f(x)-y)^2 / dk 

=2(f(x)-y) * d(kx-y) / dk

=2x(f(x)-y)

=2x(kx-y)
```

So update k by `k = k - rate * 2x(kx-y)`,by gradient descend.

And this is exactly how it's said on the textbook, so I thought this will work :-(

```
from random import uniform
k,k0=uniform(-100,100),uniform(-100,100)
for _ in range(10):
    x=uniform(-100,100)
    k=k-0.01*x*(k*x-k0*x)
    print k,k0
```

Sadly, the output:

```
-2639.75970458 -72.294275335
56444.9277867 -72.294275335
-350533.559366 -72.294275335
-315222.824967 -72.294275335
26481249.7869 -72.294275335
25795070.4808 -72.294275335
-329558179.012 -72.294275335
22212688252.9 -72.294275335
-2.2317104093e+11 -72.294275335
1.61788553661e+12 -72.294275335
```

`k` deviates from `k0` in upsetting speed :-(

I've already read wiki,google and the questionsrecommended on the right of this page, but got no idea :-( Tnanks a lot

Comment: I see that unutbu has answered your question nicely, but I'll just add that it's useful to `seed()` the random number generator. It can be annoying trying to debug programs that use random numbers when the numbers keep changing. :) You can supply `random.seed()` with any hashable object as a seed, eg a number or a string; if you omit the seed or supply `None`, then it gets seeded with the system time (which is the default seed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your "learning rate" (e.g. 0.01) smaller and the number of iterations, `N`, larger:

```
from random import uniform
learning_rate = 0.0001
N = 100
k, k0 = uniform(-100, 100), uniform(-100, 100)
for _ in range(N):
    x = uniform(-100, 100)
    k = k - learning_rate * x * (k * x - k0 * x)
    print k, k0
```